# binance websocket lag

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I am developing my own python cryptobot but when I am tracking my indicators and strategy with any event in market I lag from market about 30 seconds and it might the candle will be close and will open new candle but I am  working on old candle still.

I run it on my VPS with python 3 and linux ubuntu and I use these below library for websocket.

[python-binance](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: What is your question? Can you include your code? Please see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lag is caused by a slow client computer CPU which queues the "on message" interrupts. Try it on a client computer with higher CPU speed.

Comment: I have an AMD3950, and still slow. Problem is that some websocket commands send too much information to the client, and usually the library doesnt support that ammount of information.